# why vc-dim of the range space (R^m, {lines in R^m}) is 2?

Tags: machine-learning

I need to prove that for any positive integer $m \in N$ the range space $(X , Y)$ where $X = \mathbb{R^m}$, and $Y$ consists of lines in $\mathbb{R^m}$ has VC dimension 2.

but I know that the VC dimension of such range space are $m+1$, where am I wrong?

Comment: Does $Y$ indicate the hypothesis set? So for a 2D Perceptron $(m=2)$  the $Y$/hypothesis set would consist of 1D lines in the 2D planes, and the VC dimension would be 3? The only way I can see a situation where the VC dimension = 2 is if $m=1$ and so the input space $X \in \mathbb{R}^1$ is the x-axis. In which case, the hypothesis set would be the set of 0-dimensional hyperplanes, a.k.a., points. And, yes, all arrangements of 2 points on a line could be shattered by a point, but in general 3 points on a line cannot.

Comment: I need to prove that the vc-dim of range spaces like I described is 2  for any positive integer ∈ and not for specific integer that's why I don't understand because for m=2 the vc-dim is 3 as far as I know..

Comment: clarification: the rage space is lines of the form y=ax+b, no matter what the dimension m.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. There is a theorem that states that he VC dimension of any problem is the number of full degrees of freedom in the hypothesis set. As long as $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^1$ in the expression $y=ax+b$, then they are the only two degrees of freedom in your hypothesis set, and so VC dimension must needs be 2.

A more detailed discussion would point out that you can find values for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^1$ to satisfy $y=ax+b$ for as many as two points $(x^{(1)},y^{(1)})$ and ($x^{(2)},y^{(2)}$) where $y \in \{-1,1\}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ *provided that you go on to explain what you mean by $y=ax+b$ in this badly under-specified context.*

So here is what it can mean and still make some sense: $y=ax+b$ must be redefined as $y=A^TX+b$, where $A=(a,0,\cdots,0)$ and $X=(x_1,\cdots,x_m)^T$. To be clear, $A, X \in \mathbb{R}^m$.  No matter how we define the problem, we have created a hyperplane based on the extending the line $y=ax_1+b$ infinitely in $m-1$ orthogonal dimensions. And we will only be able to shatter 2 points with this odd-ball hypothesis set. We can control the $+$ side of the line by selecting $a$ positive or negative. We can locate the line at position $-b/a$ along the $x_1$ coordinate. But that is it. VC dimension is indeed 2.

I think the pedagogical value of this problem is to force you to think in terms of badly maimed hypothesis sets. You can still do something with them, but not much. It would have been a better worded problem had my definitions of $A$ and $B$ been included.

Comment: Tnx for the detailed answer. Honestly the question was formulate as I wrote it in the first place.

Comment: I've added the clarification due to some comments that my lecturer send me. He clarified that the range is lines for all ∈. So I guess that a,b are ,∈ℝ1 and x,y∈ℝm

Comment: In addition there is a hint that for any two distinct points, there is a unique line containing them.